# Drawing random numbers with draws in some pre-defined interval, `numpy.random.choice()`

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I would like to use `numpy.random.choice()` but make sure that the draws are spaced by at least a certain "interval":

As a concrete example,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
interval = 5
foo = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,50), 5)  ## 5 random draws between array([ 1,  2, ..., 50])
print(foo)
## array([46,  3, 29, 35, 39])
```

I would prefer these be spaced by at least the `interval+1`, i.e. 5+1=6. In the above example, this condition isn't met: there should be another random draw, as 35 and 39 are separated by 4, which is less than 6.

The array `array([46,  3, 29, 15, 39])` would be ok, as all draws are spaced by at least 6.

`numpy.random.choice(array, size)` draws `size` number of draws in `array`. Is there another function used to check the "spacing" between elements in a numpy array? I could write the above with an if/while statement, but I'm not sure how to most efficiently check the spacing of elements in a numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that inserts the spaces after drawing:

```
def spaced_choice(low, high, delta, n_samples):
    draw = np.random.choice(high-low-(n_samples-1)*delta, n_samples, replace=False)
    idx = np.argsort(draw)
    draw[idx] += np.arange(low, low + delta*n_samples, delta)
    return draw
```

Sample run:

```
spaced_choice(4, 20, 3, 4)
# array([ 5,  9, 19, 13])
spaced_choice(1, 50, 5, 5)
# array([30,  8,  1, 15, 43])
```

Please note that a draw and then accept-or-reject-and-redraw strategy can be very expensive. In the worst-case example below redrawing takes almost half a minute for just `10` samples because the accpet/reject ratio is very poor. The insert-the-spaces-afterwards method has no problems of this kind.

Time required by different methods for two examples:

```
low, high, delta, size = 1, 100, 5, 5
add_spaces            0.04245870 ms
redraw                0.11335560 ms
low, high, delta, size = 1, 20, 1, 10
add_spaces            0.03201030 ms
redraw            27881.01527220 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import types
from timeit import timeit

def f_add_spaces(low, high, delta, n_samples):
    draw = np.random.choice(high-low-(n_samples-1)*delta, n_samples, replace=False)
    idx = np.argsort(draw)
    draw[idx] += np.arange(low, low + delta*n_samples, delta)
    return draw

def f_redraw(low, high, delta, n_samples):
    foo = np.random.choice(np.arange(low, high), n_samples)
    while any(x <= delta for x in np.diff(np.sort(foo))):
        foo = np.random.choice(np.arange(low, high), n_samples)
    return foo

for l, h, k, n in [(1, 100, 5, 5), (1, 20, 1, 10)]:
    print(f'low, high, delta, size = {l}, {h}, {k}, {n}')
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
                'f(*args)', globals={'f':func, 'args':(l,h,k,n)}, number=10)*100))
```

Comment: It looks like `f_add_spaces()` might be the way to go. It's interesting there are two types of ValueErrors one gets near the "edge cases" where the interval/draw/np.arange() combination isn't mathematically possible. e.g. `f_add_spaces(1, 100, 24, 5)` gives `ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'` while `f_add_spaces(1, 100, 25, 5)` gives `ValueError: a must be greater than 0`. I'll have to write checks for these

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I'd argue that behavior is correct, since in both your examples the values simply wont't fit: 1, 26, 51, 76, 101 (gaps > 24) and 1, 27, 53, 79, 105 (gaps > 25). If you want a nicer error message you can check for high - low <= (n_samples - 1) * (delta + 1) and raise a ValueError in that case.

Comment: "I'd argue that behavior is correct, since in both your examples the values simply wont't fit: 1, 26, 51, 76, 101 (gaps > 24) and 1, 27, 53, 79, 105 (gaps > 25). " You're right (hope that was clear previously). Just an interesting observation, as it's failing in different parts. The first takes place at `File "mtrand.pyx", line 1161, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:18155)`, and the second takes place at `File "mtrand.pyx", line 1115, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17104)`. I'll write a novel warning to be thrown for users. Thanks!

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Oh, I see. That is because in the first case the first argument to `choice` evalueates to `3` which would be ok if we weren't asking for 5 distinct samples from that range. In the second case it evaluates to `-1` which doesn't make sense in any case.

Comment: Right. Both errors are from `np.random.choice()`. The first error occurs `np.random.choice(a, size, replace=False)` when `a > size`. The second error occurs when `a <= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array first to have all points in an ascending order, then use `np.diff` to find the difference between consecutive values. If any difference is smaller than the `interval`, then the condition has not been met. i.e.

```
import numpy as np

interval = 5
foo = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,50),5)
while np.any(np.diff(np.sort(foo)) <= interval):
     foo = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,50),5)
print(foo)
```

Which would loop until you get a numpy array where all values differ by atleast the `interval`.

Comment: `# condition isn't met. ` would mean in this case deleting the element(s) in the array which do not meet the conditional, and re-drawing via `numpy.random.choice()`. Given the current code, users would pop `x` from the array, and keep drawing until they can continue

Comment: I would just call the random choice again until a satisfactory array has been obtained. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I suggest using  `while np.any(np.diff(np.sort(foo)) <= interval):`  instead of list comprehension. Less shuffling of data types. Also, the OP wants the differences  to be strictly greater than `interval`, hence <= in the rejection criterion.

Comment: I worry this might take forever. If any one element in `foo` breaks the `interval` conditional, there will be another 5 draws.

Comment: That is true, this method may take a longer time as illustrated in another answer. If you aim for temporal efficiency please use that answer. However, I do believe that code should also be minimal. If your array size is small, then use this method. If not, maybe the other answer is a better way at the expense of longer code.

Comment: I actually think it's a pretty clean approach. I need to think about how to write checks though that the interval/draw/np.arange() combination isn't mathematically possible, e.g. interval=15 for 5 draws between 1 and 50 will cause an infinite loop above.